# Seemingly valid cron expression changes trigger "Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common: No valid combination of account information found."

Tags: azure-functions

I've got an Azure Function that runs on a timer. The goal is to run this function every 5 minutes, but I'm having some strange issues with the cron expression.

Given a format of `"schedule": "*/30 * * * * *"`, the script runs every 30 seconds as I'd expect with no error messages. All the script's functionality works as expected.

If I change this to `"schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"`, I would expect this to run every 5 minutes on the 0th second. What I get instead is an error message: `The listener for function 'Functions.{FunctionName}' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common: No valid combination of account information found.` The worker process then starts and initializes, but sits at a lock. This is the case with every other combination of cron expression I've tried besides the second intervals.

For reference, I'm using the Cosmos DB Emulator, but given that it works flawlessly on second intervals I can't imagine that's the source of the problem. I'm signed out of Azure when I run the function during development to isolate it from corporate accounts, but if that were the problem I'd expect the second intervals to not work either. I've found one other mention of this issue, but it doesn't seem to have been effectively resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the issue with the cron expression. Timer trigger requires a storage account, so the problem as the error message said: "`No valid combination of account information found`".

Check the `local.settings.json`, see if you got a white space like this :

```
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage = true; DevelopmentStorageProxyUri=https://127.0.0.1"
```

Remove the white space like this solved my problem.:

```
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true;DevelopmentStorageProxyUri=https://127.0.0.1"
```

Check for https and white space in all connection strings on the Settings tab.